How to return warnings from a REST API
For errors we have RFC9457 which defines Problem Details.
But what to use in case of a non fatal warning?
Example:
The client called GET /toast?color=charcoal
The server is able to handle that request and process it, but wants to inform the user that the tray for crumbles underneath the toaster is nearly full and should be emptied out.
So the server should return the toast in the body:
{
    "toast": {
        "state": "burnt"
    }
}

Is there a standard for appending warnings somehow to that body?
I'm specifically looking for a standard(s) here, not examples of how different companies are all rolling their own "standard".

I'd say it's not the responsibility of the consumer of every endpoint to check for such warnings. That information also might be exploitable in some way.

with a 200 response, the request is successfully fulfilled so it will only return the body defined. If you want to distribute further information about the resource, you can only use the body or a custom header to indicate further information. regarding a standard, using RFC9457 would probably be your best bet. Currently, they don't have a http-problem-type type defined for warning.  I recommend submitting one for future use.  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9457.html#name-defining-new-problem-types

extending your existing JSON Schema would not be a breaking change and would be fairly easy to implement as an additional root node on your response body to indicate this type of information to your consumers.

"Is there a standard for appending warnings somehow to that body?" No, there is not.

Not a current standard, but the closest thing is probably this draft: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-cedik-http-warning-02
